# Swift does not update view when @published changes

Tags: swift

Whatever I try, Swift does not seem to update the view when @published changes.

I have the following code in a view

## View

```
@StateObject var vm: DownloadController = DownloadController() // I also tried ObeservedObject or State but it doesn't seem to matter.

VStack {
        HStack {
            Image("logo_color")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 250, height: 105, alignment: .leading)
            
            Button(action: { self.showModal = true } , label: {
                Text("Help")
                    .foregroundColor(.orange)
            })
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
            
        }
        .padding(.top, 20)
        .padding(.horizontal)
        
        RefreshableScrollView(onRefresh: { done in
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
                //vm.project.removeAll();
                
                DownloadController().getProjectsByUserTokenCompletion  {
                    //vm.project = viewModel.project
                }
                
                print(vm.project)
                
                done()
            }
        }) {
            VStack {
                let project_count = vm.project.count
                
                if (project_count > 0) {
                    
                    ForEach((vm.project).reversed()) { project in
                        CardView(image: project.projectImage, project_title: project.projectName, project_details: project.projectDetail, project_url: project.projectUrl, status: "up")
                    }
                    
                    Text("End of the line")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    
                } else {
                    Text("Geen resultaten. Probeer het later opnieuw")
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 12)
            .padding(.bottom, 100)
        }
    }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    .onAppear {
        DownloadController().getProjectsByUserTokenCompletion  {
            //self.data = viewModel.project
        }
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: self.$showModal) {
        HomeHelpCard()
    }
```

## Model

```
struct getProjects: Decodable {
    let Projects: [Project]
}

struct Project: Decodable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let projectName: String
    let projectDetail: String
    let projectUrl: String
    let projectImage: String
}
```

## Controller

```
class DownloadController: ObservableObject {
     @Published var project = [Project]()

func getProjectsByUserTokenCompletion(finished: () -> Void) {
        let url = URL(string: "\(self.Api_URL)/api/v1/webhook/projects/\(self.Api_token)/\(self.UserToken ?? self.Default)")!
        
        var request  = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.setValue("Bearer \(self.Token ?? "")", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        URLSession.shared.jsonDecodableTask(with: request, decoder: decoder) { (result: Result<getProjects, Error>) in
            switch result {
            
                case .success(let project):
                    self.project = project.Projects
                    
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
        
        finished()
    }
}
```

The above works perfectly however, when I do the 'Pull to Refresh' action, it doesn't seem to update whatever I try to do. By calling `DownloadController().getProjectsByUserTokenCompletion { ... }` I try to download new data from the database (This part is not documented of course but it's just changing some text from **Lorum Ipsum** to **Test test** or whatever. This also works. When I go inside the `DownloadController()` and `print(self.project)` after it got assigned with `project.Projects` it displays the right data. However the view just does not get updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `DownloadController`

```
@StateObject var vm: DownloadController = DownloadController()
```

Is different than this

```
DownloadController().getProjectsByUserTokenCompletion
```

and this in `onAppear`

```
DownloadController().getProjectsByUserTokenCompletion
```

One cannot see what the other is doing

Every time you call `DownloadController()` you are creating a different instance

change any calls of `DownloadController()` (other than the `@StateObject`) to use the `vm` variable

```
vm.getProjectsByUserTokenCompletion
```

Comment: Aaaaaaah okay! I don't have much experience with Swift so this really helps me to understand it a lot better! Thank you.